# How to display array items with having the same title for a particular time iteratively

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to display advertisements with having the same name and these ads must work 1 minute. After that another advertisements having the same title work like this.

Controller :

```
 [Route("api/ads")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AdController : ControllerBase
    {
        IAdTblRepository adTblRepository;
        public AdController(IAdTblRepository _adTblRepository)
        {
            adTblRepository = _adTblRepository;
        }
        [Route("getads")]
        public Task<List<AdTbl>> GetSingleAd()
        {

            var ad = adTblRepository.GetAllAsync();

            return ad;
        }
    }
```

AdTblRepository

```
public async Task<List<AdTbl>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        
        return await _context.AdTbl.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Title).ToListAsync();
        
    }
```

IAdTblInterface

Task<List> GetAllAsync();

Adtbl

```
public class AdTbl
    {
        public Guid? AdID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
    }
```

[After successful run , got this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvjFu.png)

please check the above image.
I uploaded two companies ad images. Each entry accept multiple Ad images ,limit to upload is 4 . Now the result showing 8 elements. first, i want to show the 4 ads having same title . After 1 minute shows the next  ad title

ie , in first iteration i want to display only 4 images( b-copy.png , g-copy.png , y-copy.png , ro-copy.png) that having the same Ad title,

in next iteration display these images (y.png , g.png , ro.png , p.png)

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is your code currently returning? Why is that wrong / not what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Taking in consideration your question in title and what you added in description, in my opinion you don't need to change your controller, but if you want to display on front-end some items for some time, you can do it using Javascript.

You should first group array items by title (company). You can use for this for example groupBy function from JS underscore library or some other way if you prefer.

After that you can use setInterval() Javascript function which will contain logic for updating html every 60 seconds:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() { 
      // Here can be logic for adding company data in html
      i = i + 1;
      if (i == arrayItems.length) {
        i =  0;
      }
}, 60000);
```

Sorry in advance if I didn't understand your question well or if it didn't help to your problem.